# How to convert UTF-8 to Win-1251 in POST form to remote site?

Tags: php, html, forms, post, encoding

I have a php file which I need to stay in UTF-8. There's a hidden form which opens search query on remote site in new window. But that site is in windows-1251 encoding. I tried to encode search (utf to ansi etc) but the only way I achieved real result is when the whole php file is encoded in win-1251. Is there any way to keep my file in UTF but send the right POST query?
Here's my code:

```
<form method="POST" name="form0" id="form0">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search">
    <input type="submit" name="">
</form>
<?php
    // a lot of code needed to stay in UTF-8
    
    if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
        // some more code also needed to stay in UTF-8
        ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function remotesearch() {
                document.getElementById("subject").value = "<?php echo $_POST['search']); ?>";
                document.getElementById("form1").submit();
            }
        </script>
        
        <div style="display: none;">
            <form target="_blank" action="https://example.com/Search.asp" id="form1" method="post" name="form1">
                <input name="subject" type="text" value="" id="subject">
            </form>
        </div>

        <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: First of all, I’d try and slap an `accept-charset="windows-1251"` on the form. Browsers encode form parameters with the document encoding by default, but with this attribute, you’re supposed to be able to overwrite that. I have never used this myself (no need), but MDN lists the browser support for that attribute as quite good, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#Browser_compatibility

Comment: If that doesn’t help, then you could maybe stick your hidden form into an iframe - then you can have a document with a different encoding than your main one in there. (You will probably still have to convert the encoding at some point then.)

Comment: Oh yes, thank you, iframe did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CBroe mentions in the [comments underneath the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63072741/how-to-convert-utf-8-to-win-1251-in-post-form-to-remote-site/63080216#comment111535747_63072741):

> First of all, I’d try and slap an `accept-charset="windows-1251"` on the form. Browsers encode form parameters with the document encoding by default, but with this attribute, you’re supposed to be able to overwrite that. I have never used this myself (no need), but MDN lists the browser support for that attribute as quite good, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#Browser_compatibility. If that doesn’t help, then you could maybe stick your hidden form into an iframe - then you can have a document with a different encoding than your main one in there. (You will probably still have to convert the encoding at some point then.)

— an iframe solved my problem.

I made external file in windows-1251 encoding with my hidden form. Then I put it to iframe, also I made a function to convert some charachters (yeah, a bit dumb, but it works now). Here's the code:

```
<body  onload="remotesearch()">
    <form method="POST" name="form0" id="form0">
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search">
        <input type="submit" name="">
    </form>
    
    <?php
        // a lot of code needed to stay in UTF-8
        
        function fromansi($str){
            $str=strtr($str,array('%7E'=>'~','60%'=>'`','22%'=>'"','40%'=>'@','%3F'=>'?','21%'=>'!','23%'=>'#','%B9'=>'№','24%'=>'$','25%'=>'%','%5E'=>'^','26%'=>'&','%2B'=>'+','%2A'=>'*','%3A'=>':','%2C'=>',','28%'=>'(','29%'=>')','%7B'=>'{','%7D'=>'}','%5B'=>'[','%5D'=>']','%3C'=>'<','%3E'=>'>','%2F'=>'/','%C0'=>'А','%E0'=>'а','%C1'=>'Б','%E1'=>'б','%C2'=>'В','%E2'=>'в','%C3'=>'Г','%E3'=>'г','%C4'=>'Д','%E4'=>'д','%C5'=>'Е','%E5'=>'е','%A8'=>'Ё','%B8'=>'ё','%C6'=>'Ж','%E6'=>'ж','%C7'=>'З','%E7'=>'з','%C8'=>'И','%E8'=>'и','%C9'=>'Й','%E9'=>'й','%CA'=>'К','%EA'=>'к','%CB'=>'Л','%EB'=>'л','%CC'=>'М','%EC'=>'м','%CD'=>'Н','%ED'=>'н','%CE'=>'О','%EE'=>'о','%CF'=>'П','%EF'=>'п','%D0'=>'Р','%F0'=>'р','%D1'=>'С','%F1'=>'с','%D2'=>'Т','%F2'=>'т','%D3'=>'У','%F3'=>'у','%D4'=>'Ф','%F4'=>'ф','%D5'=>'Х','%F5'=>'х','%D6'=>'Ц','%F6'=>'ц','%D7'=>'Ч','%F7'=>'ч','%D8'=>'Ш','%F8'=>'ш','%D9'=>'Щ','%F9'=>'щ','%DA'=>'Ъ','%FA'=>'ъ','%DB'=>'Ы','%FB'=>'ы','%DC'=>'Ь','%FC'=>'ь','%DD'=>'Э','%FD'=>'э','%DE'=>'Ю','%FE'=>'ю','%DF'=>'Я','%FF'=>'я'));
             return $str;}
        
        if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
            // some more code also needed to stay in UTF-8
            
            $search_fromansi = fromansi($_POST['search']);
            ?>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function remotesearch() {
                    var iframe = document.getElementById("externalfileframe");
                    iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("subject").value = "<?php echo $search_fromansi; ?>"; // search field ID in external file
                    iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("form1").submit(); // form ID in external file
                }
            </script>

            <?php
        }
    ?>

    <iframe src="file_in_1251.php" id="externalfileframe" style="border: none; height: 0;"></iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: How did you use the iFrame? Your answer is so short that it can hardly be called an answer. Could you extend it with more information to make it into a good answer? :)

Comment: @Andreas you're right, I was a bit excited and rushing. Edited my answer